# Динамическая подгрузка файлов Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Подскажите как вот это реализовать с помощью

```html
 <form><select><option></option></select></form>
```

```html
<form>
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="File1"> <input id="btn2" type="button" value="File2"> <input id="btn3" type="button" value="File3"> <input id="btn4" type="button" value="File4">
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
   $('#btn1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "File1.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#container").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
   
   $('#btn2').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "File2.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#container").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
   $('#btn3').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "File3.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#container").html(html);
     }
    });
   });
   $('#btn4').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: "File4.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
      $("#container").html(html);
     }
    });
   });   
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вот так:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {//слушаем, когда изменится значение селекта
  fileGet($(this).val());//при изменении вызываем функцию, с текущим(выбранным) значением селекта
});

function fileGet(file) {//собссно тот же код, обернутый в функцию
  file = file + ".php";
  console.log(file);
  $.ajax({
    url: file,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      $("#container").html(html);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select>
    <option value='File1'>File1</option>
    <option value='File2'>File2</option>
    <option value='File3'>File3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не работает, не могу понять ...

Comment: @Андрей мб потому что у тебя имя файла с заглавной начиналось, у меня со строчной. Сейчас поменял, попробуй так

Comment: Всё по файлам правильно, у меня со строчной. Только не подгружает контент.

Comment: @Андрей, немного поменял код, посмотри, что будет в консоль спамить. Если имена в консоли совпадают с именами файлов, проблема в запросе, но он под копирку был взят из твоего примера

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

Comment: @Андрей а, дак тю, jQ то я тебе не подключу удаленно. Вон в примере кода есть линк на библиотеку: `<script src="https...></script>`

Comment: Дак подключена библиотека.

Comment: @Андрей значит криво скопировал код. В сниппете все отрабатывает нормально, без ошибок. Приведи хоть строку где возникает.

Comment: У меня подключен <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> может конфликт

Comment: @Андрей что-то ссылка не совсем рабочей выглядит. А точнее - совсем нерабочей. `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js` - копировать - вставить - проверить

Comment: Всё гудд работает, спасибо. У меня в подгружаемом файле highcharts ложится.

Comment: @Андрей, ну я думаю, что это уже совсем другой вопрос =)

Comment: Да. 100%. Спасибо!

Comment: А каким образом изменить путь к расположению файла?